# Issue in installing APP : Launcher App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, launcher, android-launcher

I am just creating my custom launcher application and As I come to know below changes are required to make simple launcher in AndroidManifest file.

Lookout :

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AppsListActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
```

Since there is no line like : `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`, I can not install the app. 
Android studio giving me "error in installing application".

What might be the solution ? Thanks.

Comment: try installing your app manually to your phone and then press the home button. Your app should be visible in the selection box for choosing launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your `<intent-filter>` should look like

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: First gone through this : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358